# Is it clear what the pronoun is referring to in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, pronouns

In the following sentence, is there any ambiguity about the pronoun "**they**"? they refers to **pumps**, is it clear?

> The current flows into the electric motors that drive the **pumps** that
> expel water when **they** contract.

Comment: Ideally, whole sentence can be rephrased like, “The current flows into the electric motors which drive the pumps, which in turn expel water when they contract.”

Answer (score 2):

In theory, yes there is a little ambiguity, since your sentence mentions two different "things", i.e. 'pumps' and 'electric motors', either of which could be the subject.

In reality, the context makes it fairly obvious in this case that it refers to 'pumps' since 'motors' are unlikely to 'contract'.